# dropdown menu not working on mobile, document click not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I made a simple dropdown menu where it toggle on `.dropdown-toggle` click and close on `.dropdown-toggle` and `document` click. Everything works great on desktop. However it doesn't works on mobile when you try to close the dropdown menu by clicking on the `document`.

jquery

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
     $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
$(".dropdown-menu").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
$(".dropdown-menu").hide();
});
```

any help?

Comment: try `$(document).on("click touchstart"`
because mobile devices has only touch events

Comment: it works, thank you very much